# Explicitly instantiate templates using a tuple

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

To explicitly instantiate a class template I can do the following:

```
//.h
template<typename T>
class Foo{};


//.cpp
template class Foo<float>;
```

This is nice because the `Foo<float>` class will only have to be instantiated once now when being used from many places. Would it be possible to explicitly instantiate `Foo<T>` with a tuple of predetermined types? Lets say the tuple is `std::tuple<float, int, bool>`, which I want to use to instantiate `Foo<float>, Foo<int>` and `Foo<bool>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to conveniently instantiate several `Foo` template classes, you could simply provide a wrapper for that:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class MultiFoo : public Foo<Ts>... {};
```

and then to instantiate several template classes at once:

```
template class MultiFoo<int, double, bool>;
```

which will instantiate `Foo<int>`, `Foo<double>`, and `Foo<bool>` for you.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HHpkq6)

If you actually have a tuple, then you can provide an explicit specialization for that:

```
template<typename ...>
class MultiFoo;

template<typename ...Ts>
class MultiFoo<tuple<Ts...>> : public Foo<Ts>... {};
```

and instantiate several `Foo`s with:

```
template class MultiFoo<tuple<int,double, bool>>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/g3P36G), where I added my own tuple so that the output is actually visible. This should work exactly the same way for `std::tuple`.

Note that if you want to explicitly instantiate templates so that they are visible in other translation units, you need to use the `extern` keyword for that. e.g.

```
extern template class Foo<int>;
```

and

```
extern template class MultiFoo<int, double, bool>;
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the types stored in a tuple that will be changed later.

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try that out.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe added the tuple version.

Comment: This results in unresolved external symbols when using Foo<T> in another translation unit. It doesn't seem to be explicitly instantiating Foo, nice idea though didn't try that one yet.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe I've added the solution to this to the answer.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem though because now I still need to write out the list of instances I want in the header manually, without being able to update them when updating the tuple.

Comment: @AndreasLoanjoe What exactly do you mean by "update the tuple?" If you're doing the update at run time, this is not possible.

Comment: No I mean when a type gets added to the system (by editing the tuple), I want it to be part of the explicit instantiations that can be seen from another translation unit. If I have to indicate every version as extern I cannot do that without macros.